# Justifiability of excluding outlier that single-handedly drives a correlation

Tags: correlation, outliers, reporting

I have this cross-subjects correlation between scores on two different tests, which is at significant (r=.43, p=.02):

[image]

One of the subjects does appear as an outlier given his score on test1 (x axis). Sure enough, it can be said it was he who was driving the correlation, as when I compute the correlation without him, significance is lost (r=.34, p=.08).

I am, however, unsure whether it is justified to exclude this subject on the grounds of him being an outlier, and report the reduced sample (N-1) results. This is because I have no reason to suspect his score on test1 is incorrectly measured, or that the test score is irrelevant in the lower ranges - that's just what his score is.

Seems to me this is a very arbitrary decision and a very grey line. Is there in fact a correct way as to how to proceed, or is it "anyone's guess"?

Comment: Can I ask how you identified your outlier? If you think all your data are real, then there's no real reason to exclude.

Comment: @reid is correct in questioning the logic behind excluding this individual's results. Chances are your correlation is *Pearson*. Try a *Spearman* correlation which is based on ranks and is more robust to outliers. I'm willing to bet it will be significant with and without this data point.

Comment: @Reid: I only eye-balled it; but he would probably come out as an outlier even if using a definition based on number of SDs away from mean etc. Anyway, you both seem to confirm that there is no real reason why to exclude this subject, even if he might be deemed an outlier.

Comment: @DJohnson: If using the Spearman correlation, the coefficient is roughly the same, but does indeed remain sig even when I take that data point out

Comment: "when I compute the correlation without him, significance is lost" — See: Gelman, A., & Stern, H. (2006). The difference between "significant" and "not significant" is not itself statistically significant. *The American Statistician, 60*, 328–331. doi:10.1198/000313006X152649

Comment: That\s an interesting paper, but my question is really whether a score that is much lower in comparison to an otherwise homogenous distribution can qualify as an 'outlier' on that basis alone. Also, whether the fact that this data point is single-handedly driving the correlation makes the outlier diagnostic more believable, although I suspect your point has to do specifically with this latter point

Comment: Thanks again for your inputs & let me know if any of you has further thoughts. So far I gather that it would not be incorrect/misleading to report the full-sample correlation, even if it's mainly driven by one subject, since there are no good grounds on which to dismiss that subject's score as an outlier.